# Using bash script to use return status of one C program as arg to another

Tags: c, bash

I have two compiled .c files and I am trying to take the exit status of the first and use it as an arg to the next one.

```
#!/bash/bin

./decipher $1
key = $?
./cipher $key $1 $2
```

This is what I am typing on the command line
`$ ./decryption_tool.bs ceaser1.txt output.txt` 
.ceaser1.txt is an encrypted message and decipher will return a key and cipher should take that key and unencrypt it. Both files work outside of the script as well, but when i use the script I get this error.

```
./decryption_tool.bs: line 4: key: command not found
./decryption_tool.bs: line 5:  5937 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./cipher $key $1 $2
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't think you can use spaces when setting variables: `key=$?`

Comment: Remove the spaces around the equals sign (i.e. key=$? )

Comment: @MichaelFralish : Aside from this, I find it a bit odd that you are making an encryption system, where the key must be a number between 0 and 128....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things wrong:

1. You cannot have spaces when you set variables in shell script - it should be `key=$?` instead of `key = $?`
2. Invalid shebang: not `#!/bash/bin`, but `#!/bin/bash` or even better `#!/usr/bin/env bash`
3. It would be good to surround variables in double quotes: `./cipher "$key" "$1" "$2"`
4. Why file extension is `.bs`? For shell script it's `.sh` and Bash doesn't have its own separate version

Comment: Wow, super quick responses. The spaces fixed it. I corrected the other things too. Thank you